# Prove that this function is not integrable: $f(x)$ is $1-x$ for $x$ rational, and $1/x$ for $x$ irrational

Tags: real-analysis

How do I prove that the function 
$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
1-x &,\text{when}\; x \;\text{is rational} \\
1/x &, \text{when}\; x \;\text{is irrational}
\end{cases}$$ is not integrable on every interval $[a,b]$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You'll find that the community here prefers/expects a question to involve more than a simple problem statement. Please include something about what you know of the problem and/or where you got stuck. This information helps answerers tailor their responses to your skill level, while avoiding wasting time telling you things you already know. (Plus, it helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) **Help us help you.**

Comment: Riemann or Lebesgue integral?

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of integral, it is easy to check that for any partition of [a,b], the upper integral never equals the lower integral. Thus the function not integrable.